In this case, is it appropriate to perform $(a\lor b)\land(c\lor d)\iff(a\land c)\lor(d\land b)$?
In this earlier post of mine, we discussed the inequality, $\lvert x-a\rvert<\lvert x-b\rvert$.
With help from this answer, I was able to fill a gap in my knowledge regarding the inequality manipulation. The complete process is as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lvert x-a\rvert<\lvert x-b\rvert&\iff\underbrace{(-\lvert x-b\rvert<x-a)}_{(P)}\land\underbrace{(x-a<\lvert x-b\rvert)}_{(Q)}\\
(P)&\iff\lvert x-b\rvert>a-x\\
&\iff(x-b<x-a)\lor(x-b>a-x)\\
&\iff(b>a)\lor\left(x>\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\\
(Q)&\iff(x-b<a-x)\lor(x-b>x-a)\\
&\iff\left(x<\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\lor(b<a)\\
\therefore(P)\land(Q)&\iff\left((b>a)\lor\left(x>\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\right)\land\left(\left(x<\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\lor(b<a)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
This should be equivalent to:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x>\frac{a+b}{2}&\quad\mbox{if}\quad a>b\\
x<\frac{a+b}{2}&\quad\mbox{if}\quad a<b
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
If so, what rule(s) would enable me to go between the following inequalities? (I find the second one more intuitive than the first, but it is just an inference - I did not deduce it.)
$$(P)\land(Q)\overset{?}{\iff}\left(b>a\land x<\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\lor\left(a>b\land x>\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$$

Edit:
According to the comments section, I am to use distribution laws from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property.
I looked through the resource, and the statement which seemed to best fir my situation was under the "Double Distribution" section. Namely;
$$
(P\lor Q)\land (R\lor S)\iff((P\land R)\lor (R\land S))\lor((Q\land R)\lor (Q\land S))
$$
So, let's label our expression:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\therefore(P)\land(Q)&\iff\left(\underbrace{(b>a)}_{(P)}\lor\underbrace{\left(x>\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}_{(Q)}\right)\land\left(\underbrace{\left(x<\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}_{(R)}\lor\underbrace{(b<a)}_{(S)}\right)\\
&\iff(P\lor Q)\land (R\lor S)\\
&\iff((P\land R)\lor (R\land S))\lor((Q\land R)\lor (Q\land S))\\
&\iff
\left(
\left(
    (b>a)\land \left(x<\frac{a+b}{2}\right)
\right)
\lor 
\left(
    \left(x<\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\land (b<a)
\right)
\right)
\lor
\left(
\left(
    \left(x>\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\land \left(x<\frac{a+b}{2}\right)
\right)
\lor 
\left(
    \left(x>\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\land (b<a)
\right)
\right)\\
&\overset{?}{\nLeftrightarrow}\left(b>a\land x<\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\lor\left(a>b\land x>\frac{a+b}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Yes, see Distributivity.

@MauroALLEGRANZA According to that article (under Double Distribution), $(P\lor Q)\land (R\lor S)\iff((P\land R)\lor (R\land S))\lor((Q\land R)\lor (Q\land S))$. This is a much larger expression than the one I got. Am I making a mistake? I will edit the post to include this.

$$
(P\lor Q)\land (R\lor S)\iff((P\land R)\lor (\color{red}P\land S))\lor((Q\land R)\lor (Q\land S))
$$
In your example, $P\land S$ and $Q\land R$ are false, so there remains
$$(P\land R)\lor (Q\land S).$$

Thank you! I was wondering if it was the case that it reduced. My typo didn't help either ;-)

You are welcome, but I rolled back your last edit, because this major change was invalidating my answer.

I was just trying to improve the question, sorry about that. Good that you caught that.

Glad you don't take it bad. See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29824

I'm always happy to receive constructive criticism.
